# How to add array new key value ( javascript )?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to add array new key value ( javascript ) ?

sample image 
http://i.hizliresim.com/dj3OLn.png

example this my array

```
source.localdata[0].c_Id="2d5955ee-415b-470a-8700-3ae65ee122db"
                    Name ="mike"
                    LastName="jonas"


source.localdata[1].c_C_ID"b851c285-035f-4a51-8237-1e3c3528e089"
                    Name ="richard"
                    LastName="gere"
```

and I want to enter key and value data

```
source.localdata[0].Address = "mike for address"
source.localdata[1].Address = "richard for address"
```

..more

**output**

```
source.localdata[0].c_Id="2d5955ee-415b-470a-8700-3ae65ee122db"
                    Name ="mike"
                    LastName="jonas"
                    Address = "mike for address"

source.localdata[1].c_C_ID"b851c285-035f-4a51-8237-1e3c3528e089"
                    Name ="richard"
                    LastName="gere"
                    Address = "richard for address"
```

I wrote this code but I am getting error
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'push'

```
function dataSourceCompare(newdata) {

for (var i = 0; i < source.localdata.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < newdata.dynamicColumns.length; j++) {

        if (crewItems[i].c_C_ID === newdata.dynamicColumns[j].ColumnValue) {
            source.localdata[i].push([newdata.dynamicColumns[j].ColumnName, newdata.dynamicColumns[j].ColumnValue]);

        }             
    }                                                   
}
```

}

thank you

Comment: try ... localdata.push( ...

Comment: @johnSmith He wants to add it to an object, so he should actually do `localdata[0].c_Address = "Address for Mike"` (judging from his screenshot the other keys are also prefixed by `"c_"`).

Comment: hi john and Daniël 
but, I don't want this new create index,I want to add  in old index data and I do not have my static address line , I want to create dynamic key value .. sample image http://i.hizliresim.com/dj3OLn.png

Comment: @user3575477 I know, my code would not create a new index, it would add a property `c_Address` to an existing localdata entry. But the answer already showed you how to do it, using your `dynamicColumns` :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array.push() is used to add new elements to an array, and cannot be used on a plain javascript object. What you want to do is add a new propriety to an object, with a dynamic property name, and here's how to do it:

```
source.localdata[i][newdata.dynamicColumns[j].ColumnName] = newdata.dynamicColumns[j].ColumnValue;
```